# Django models - Circular-Import-Issue

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-models

My Django-Project uses Three Apps, `chat, user, sowi`. Every App having models structured in the following way. I'm getting an error when starting the Server, i think it is because i have circular Imports. How do i fix this issue?

**chat/models.py**

```
from user.models import User

class Chat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="private")


class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**user/models.py**

```
from chat.models import Chat
from sowi.models import Sowi

class User(AbstractUser):
    chats = models.ManyToManyField(Chat, blank=True)
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(Sowi, related_name="subscriptions", blank=True)
    memberships = models.ManyToManyField(Sowi, related_name="memberships", blank=True)
    blocked = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="blocked", blank=True)
```

**sowi/models.py**

```
from chat.models import Chat, Message
from user.models import User

class Sowi(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chat = models.OneToOneField(Chat, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Error Message**:

```
File "*/sowi/models.py", line 9, in <module>
    from chat.models import Chat, Message
  File "*/chat/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from user.models import User
  File "*/user/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from chat.models import Chat
ImportError: cannot import name 'Chat' from 'chat.models'
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It would help if you offered more context.  You don't even have the line represented in your error in your example code.

Comment: @eatmeimadanish You're right, i added it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is better to refer to models with string literals, than to refer to it with references to the model class. Django can handle this and will automatically resolve these:

```
# chat/models.py

from django.db import models

class Chat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="private")

class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey('user.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# user/models.py

from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    chats = models.ManyToManyField(Chat, blank=True)
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField('sowi.Sowi', related_name="subscriptions", blank=True)
    memberships = models.ManyToManyField('sowi.Sowi', related_name="memberships", blank=True)
    blocked = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="blocked", blank=True)

# sowi/models.py

from django.db import models

class Sowi(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('user.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chat = models.OneToOneField('chat.Chat', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

It is even better when you [reference the user model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) to set the [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL), and use this setting, such that if you later change your mind, you can more conveniently change this:

```
# chat/models.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Chat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="private")

class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# user/models.py

from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    chats = models.ManyToManyField(Chat, blank=True)
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField('sowi.Sowi', related_name="subscriptions", blank=True)
    memberships = models.ManyToManyField('sowi.Sowi', related_name="memberships", blank=True)
    blocked = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="blocked", blank=True)

# sowi/models.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Sowi(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chat = models.OneToOneField('chat.Chat'
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. Once again, you saved my a**. Keep up the awesome Help!

Comment: saved a lot of time for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    chats = models.ManyToManyField('chat.Chat', blank=True)
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField('sowi.Sowi', related_name="subscriptions", blank=True)
    memberships = models.ManyToManyField('sowi.Sowi', related_name="memberships", blank=True)
    blocked = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="blocked", blank=True)
```

The problem with your code is that you're importing `Chat` and `Sowi` in user `models.py`, and then you're trying to import user `models` in `Chat` and `Sowi`. You see the Circular Import there?