# module not found error even though modules are in place

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I had this error previously but at an instant, it was somehow fixed, but now it seems to crawl back,don't know where is the issue, thanks in advance

**Directory structure**

```
food_deliveryapp
|- manage.py
|- food_deliveryapp
|- customers 
|- entries
|- restaurants
|    |- __init__.py
|    |- admin.py 
|    |- apps.py 
|    |- models.py
|       |- City
|       |- Restraunts 
|    |- views.py
|    |- tests.py
|    |- migrations 
|    
|- static
|- templates
```

my modules and models are in place but still getting this error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\food_deliveryapp\menus\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from restaurants.models import Restraunts
  File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\food_deliveryapp\restaurants\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from customers.models import *
  File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\food_deliveryapp\customers\models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from restaurants.models import City
ImportError: cannot import name 'City' from 'restaurants.models' (C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\food_deliveryapp\restaurants\models.py)
```

Comment: That's a circular import. Restaurant models are importing customer models which are importing restaurant models...

Comment: As @AKX said, this looks a lot like a circular import. If you include the code in `customers\models.py` then perhaps there a way to do this without importing the model & causing the issue.

Comment: how do I rectify this? i have heard about circular import

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934270/django-models-circular-import-issue) - This link explains how to avoid circular import. See if that helps. Else, post your models.py to give more concrete suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, you seem to have a circular import between your models.

- You can move your imports inside the functions that need them from the module level, or
- if you need to reference models for foreign keys etc., name them as strings (`"restaurants.City"`) and Django will resolve them later.